# Conda activate in script

Tags: python, conda

To run a Python program I take run the following manually:

```
conda activate sentence-splitter-service
python3 scripts/serve.py  /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-sentence-request-local /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-language-request-local /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-document-response-local  --port 8887
```

Can I run both of these in a shell script?

Comment: You should be able to run pretty much anything in a shell script.  Have you tried it?  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes, you can. Whether it does what you want it to do is a separate question entirely, but since you haven't told us what the desired behavior is nor given us the contents of your scripts, we can't answer that question for you.

Answer (score 5):

`conda activate` is for an interactive shell only (i.e. not a shell script). If you want a specific env to run a script, then use `conda run -n sentence-splitter-service python scripts/serve.py ...` where -n specifies the environment name. As an example:

```sh
# This shows that my virtualenv is indeed on my path
conda run -n testenv python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', 'C:\\Users\\cn18933\\Miniconda3\\envs\\testenv\\python38.zip', ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe [using `conda run` should be the preferred solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70512291/570918), however, one can also use the shebang to indicate the shell should run in **login-mode**:

**script.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
conda activate sentence-splitter-service
python3 scripts/serve.py  /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-sentence-request-local /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-language-request-local /opt/acorn/file-stream/acorn-document-response-local  --port 8887
```

This assumes that the user executing the script has run `conda init` to configure their shell resource file (e.g., `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) to initialize the Conda shell functionality.

Comment: I tried the shebang as you have in line 1 above, but got "/usr/bin/env: `bash -l`: No such file or directory

Comment: @Woodsman Can depend on your system. Another variant is simply `#!/bin/bash -l` (i.e., don't assume `bash` is currently on `PATH`). For Windows, I'm not sure what the alternative is.